# gnome shell developement step by step debugger

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extensions

Is there any way to have a step by step debugger and variable browser in gnome shell ?
I had a look at the wiki page : 
https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions

and I already tryed to find this in look glass : 
https://wiki.gnome.org/GnomeShell/LookingGlass

I'm looking for some kind of firebug-like tool for gnome-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there currently isn't such a thing. I know many people who would be overjoyed if you were to start writing one, though.

Comment: I understand, but I don't think that I'm able to do that, thanks though.